# Why wont this pick up key listeners?

Tags: java

So i'm trying to make the block move with WASD keys, I've been watching a youtube series on how to make a basic game, but putting my own twist in it. In the Video his key inputs work fine, but mine don't.

```java
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter implements KeyListener {

   Handler handler;

   public KeyInput(Handler handler ) {
      this.handler = handler;
   }

   public void keyPresed(KeyEvent e) {

      for (int i = 0; i<handler.object.size(); i++) {
         GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
         if (tempObject.getId() == ID.Player) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) handler.setUp(true);
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) handler.setDown(true);
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) handler.setLeft(true);
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) handler.setRight(true);         
         }
      }
   }      
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
      for (int i = 0; i<handler.object.size(); i++) {
         GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
         if (tempObject.getId() == ID.Player) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) handler.setUp(false);
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) handler.setDown(false);
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) handler.setLeft(false);
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) handler.setRight(false);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

```java
   public GameObject(int x, int y, ID id) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.id = id;

   }

   public abstract void tick();
   public abstract void render(Graphics g);
   public abstract Rectangle getBounds();


   public ID getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(ID id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public int getX() {
      return x;
   }
   public void setX(int x) {
      this.x = x;
   }
   public int getY() {
      return y;
   }
   public void setY(int y) {
      this.y = y;
   }
   public float getVelX() {
      return velX;
   }
   public void setVelX(float velX) {
      this.velX = velX;
   }
   public float getVelY() {
      return velY;
   }
   public void setVelY(float velY) {
      this.velY = velY;
   }   

}
```

```java
   private boolean up = false, down = false, right = false, left = false;

   public boolean isUp() {
      return up;
   }
   public void setUp(boolean up) {
      this.up = up;
   }
   public boolean isDown() {
      return down;
   }
   public void setDown(boolean down) {
      this.down = down;
   }
   public boolean isLeft() {
      return left;
   }
   public void setLeft(boolean left) {
      this.left = left;
   }
   public boolean isRight() {
      return right;
   }
   public void setRight(boolean right) {
      this.right = right;
   }

}
```

```java
public class Wizard extends GameObject {
   int velX;
   int velY;

   Handler handler; 

   public Wizard(int x, int y, ID id, Handler handler) {
      super(x,y,id);
      this.handler = handler;
   }

   public void tick() {
      x += velX;
      y += velY;
      if(handler.isUp()) velY = -5;
      else if(!handler.isDown()) velY =0;

      if(handler.isDown()) velY = 5;
      else if(!handler.isUp()) velY =0;

      if(handler.isLeft()) velX = -5;
      else if(!handler.isRight()) velX =0;

      if(handler.isRight()) velX = 5;
      else if(!handler.isLeft()) velX =0;

   }
```

I have this `java 
handler = new Handler();
addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));
this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));` in my main game class

I also understand that many of the imports aren't being used.
I get no errors, just cant move block. Sorry for all the code, i'm just trying to show every point that affected by the key inputs.

Comment: If you click on the window are you able to move the square?

Comment: no,  I don't think this matters, but i am using a laptop (if that could be a problem).  I've tried minimizing, clicking, right clicking, etc. nothing has worked

Comment: You misspelled `keyPressed`. Missing an `s` in your code.

Comment: Wow, that fixed it. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
@Override 
public void keyPresed(KeyEvent e){
```

&

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
```

above the native methods of the KeyListener